# ffmpeg: specify sequence length when encoding MPEG2 video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to encode some MPEG2 video and would like to specify video sequence size, probably in terms of number of frames of GOP. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-g`. From `ffmpeg -h full | grep "group of picture"`:

```
  -g <int> set the group of picture (GOP) size (default 12)
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not the same as sequence size though.